# Conditionally importing JS library

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module

In my Rails 6.x app, I was using Webpacker in order to compile my styles and transpile my JS.

As part of my apps upgrade to Rails 7, I scrapped Webpacker (as it's no longer recommended) and switched over to the new cssbundling-rails and jsbundling-rails gems.

These are super fast and sooo much easier to use.

However, I just ran a Lighthouse report on my site and I think certain pages on my site are loading all my JS even though a lot of it is not even executed on most pages.

For example I have a script that plays audio using the Plyr library on one page.

My script for this, at the top has an import like:

`import Plyr from 'plyr'`

I've tried to conditionalism this by checking if a specific element exists on the page first before importing but it didn't like that.

How can I only perform some of these imports when they are necessary and not when they are not.

How do I convert the above to be conditional?

Thanks,
Neil

UPDATE:

My updated script:

```
if (document.querySelector('audio')) {
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    import('plyr').then(Plyr => {
        const player = new Plyr(audio, {
            'controls' : ['play'],
            'autoplay' : false
        })
    });
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Plyr2 is not a constructor.

How can I access the `Plyr` object?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `import Plyr from 'plyr'`, you can use dynamic import of
`import('plyr')` which you can use anywhere, including conditional logic. Keep in mind, dynamic imports return promises. So async/await
So,

```
if(somevalue === true){
   import('plyr').then(resp => doSomething)
}
```

Comment: Hi @issayah,  Thanks for the answer.  I've updated my code in my OP.   I'm getting some errors and not too sure why?  Could you please take a look?

Comment: @rctneil: Do a `console.log(Plyr)` to see what it is. The value will be an object with a `default` property and a property for every named export.

Comment: @FelixKling Hi!  The output of that is https://dropover.cloud/a6030d

Comment: A console log would be interesting. Or taking a look at what the plyr package is exporting. I'm not sure why it's doing that, beyond just using the wrong exported function.

Comment: @Issayah The console.log is shown in the image linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh. It's still early lmao. Try using Plyr.default. I think it's wrapped in the import function

Comment: That worked.   Why do I need to use .default on it?   While testing, I tried this dynamic import on another module elsewhere and it's having the same issue.  Do I really need to add .default after the module name in the .then each time i use it?  Can I do it up the top globally somehow?

Comment: Regular imports import the data directly, whereas dynamic import returns a module object, rather than the data. If it wasn't that way, there would be no ability to differentiate between exported data, and an exported default. It's just how it works. I think of it the same as fetching data using axios. Pretty much always gotta do .data to get the useful stuff.